# Google plus API for fetching business reviews?

Tags: php, api, google-plus

Is there any php api to get business reviews from google plus?

sample business page url:  https://plus.google.com/112164489386569071900/about?gl=IN&hl=en-IN

Answer (score 6):

I strongly suggest you to use Google Places API:
I guess the results are the same as the one displayed on G+

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details

Answer (score 3):

Reviews are now available via the API. See the Place Details API - https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details

Here is a [sample response](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details#PlaceDetailsResponses).

EDIT: There is a limit of 5 reviews.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't, the [Google Plus api](https://developers.google.com/+/api/) is still very limited, it only has access to:

- Users
- Posts
- Comments

As an alternative, you could look into the [Yelp API](http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/business).